# Creating a global method for phpmailer with static method

Tags: php, class, phpmailer, static-methods

Hi I'm getting this error when I instantiate static a method which sends email with given objects. I'm not sure my approach is right tough. I'm using slim framework with autoloader and I love using PDO where I want and I want to same with phpmailer without having set up everything to send an email.

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

<?php
    namespace lib;
    use lib\Config;
    use PDO;
    class Core {

        public $dbh;
        public $phpmail;

        private static $instance;

        private function __construct() {

            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . Config::read('db.host') .
                   ';dbname='    . Config::read('db.basename') .
                   ';port='      . Config::read('db.port') .
                   ';connect_timeout=15';
            $user = Config::read('db.user');
            $password = Config::read('db.password');
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

            $this->phpmail = new PHPMailer;

        }

        public static function getInstance() {
            if (!isset(self::$instance))
            {
                $object = __CLASS__;
                self::$instance = new $object;
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }

        public static function SendEmail ($fromAddress, $fromName, $toAddress, $isHTML = true, $emailContent) {

            $this->phpmail->From = $fromAddress;
            $this->phpmail->FromName = $fromName;
            $this->phpmail->addAddress($toAddress);

            $this->phpmail->isHTML($isHtml);
            $this->phpmail->Subject = 'Test';
            $this->phpmail->Body = $emailContent;

            if(!$this->phpmail->send())
                return $mail->ErrorInfo;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
```

this is how I call it in one of my router or in model

```
<?php

$mail = \lib\Core::SendEmail('nor-reply@domain.com', 'Webiste', 'user@domain.com', true, $email_content);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Any instance field or method (accessed via `$this`) is not available from a static context. A static method is just a procedure (give it an input, it gives you an output). When you instantiate a class its constructor is called and instance variables are populated (and therefore become accessible).

It seems like you need an instance because of the details held in the PHPMailer object, so you will need to remove the `static` from the `SendMail` method.

You will then need to instantiate your `Core` class:

```
$core = new Core();
$core->SendMail($fromAddress, $fromName, $toAddress, $isHTML = true, $emailContent);
```

**EDIT:**

Suggested way of keeping `SendMail` static:

```
<?php
namespace lib;
use lib\Config;
use PDO;
class Core {

    public $dbh;

    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() {

        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . Config::read('db.host') .
               ';dbname='    . Config::read('db.basename') .
               ';port='      . Config::read('db.port') .
               ';connect_timeout=15';
        $user = Config::read('db.user');
        $password = Config::read('db.password');
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance))
        {
            $object = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $object;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function SendEmail ($fromAddress, $fromName, $toAddress, $isHTML = true, $emailContent) {

        $phpmail = new PHPMailer();
        $phpmail->From = $fromAddress;
        $phpmail->FromName = $fromName;
        $phpmail->addAddress($toAddress);

        $phpmail->isHTML($isHtml);
        $phpmail->Subject = 'Test';
        $phpmail->Body = $emailContent;

        if(!$phpmail->send())
            return $phpmail->ErrorInfo;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Then call it using:

```
Core::SendMail('nor-reply@domain.com', 'Webiste', 
    'user@domain.com', true, $email_content)
```

Comment: how can I make it just like PDO called in the same class then? thanks.

Comment: You can do: `$core = new Core($fromAddress, $fromName, $toAddress, $isHTML = true, $emailContent)`, but make sure you declare these arguments as parameters in your `__construct()` function, and then call `$this->SendMail` from there.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't need PHPMailer as an instance, remove it from your constructor (and remove `public $phpmail`), and instantiate it within the `SendMail` function. That way you can keep `SendMail` static.

Comment: Edited my answer for you. Suggested way of keeping `SendMail` static